# There is a class object in the code, but its type is undeclared and cannot be used

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk, xcode11.2.1

Sorry for the title, it may sound confusing, but actually here is the problem.

I am using an imported module '*DJISDK*' and I have an object in use from that library. When I'm trying to get the type of that object, it gives me the type.

```
     print(type(of: object))
```

I get the type which is *DUXCameraSettingsNavigationBar*.
But when I am trying to check the type of object like this

```
     if object is DUXCameraSettingsNavigationBar { }
```

I am getting an error that says - "**Use of undeclared type 'DUXCameraSettingsNavigationBar'**".

The searches of that class in the podfiles didn't give any results. Importing all the other related modules didn't help either.

Please explain me how is that possible, and if I can somehow access that class, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the API reference for the DUX library of the DJI SDK. It seems like you are trying to access an internal/private object. For more try looking up the official DJI DUX Documentation page here: [DJI DUX Documentation](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/AutoExposureLockWidget.html). Hope this helps!